Transfer User Identity on redirect page ASP.NET
After I login I'm able to open the Dashboard page and EbayAuthController as authorized.
Pure example is when I debug the Ebay()

I'm able to expose the User object. But when it comes to EbayCallback() the value is always unauthorized.
Seems like after I Redirect to the authorizationUrl for ebay oauth I lose my values so further I'm unauthorized.
In my Program.cs
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax; // Ensure this is set correctly
    options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login2";
});

Program.cs Pastebin
namespace Skote.Controllers
{
     [Authorize]
    public class EbayAuthController : Controller
    { 

        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<EbayAuthController> _logger;

        public EbayAuthController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<EbayAuthController> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Ebay()
        {
            var authorizationUrl = $"https://auth.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?";
            return Redirect(authorizationUrl);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> EbayCallback(string code)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                return BadRequest("Authorization code is missing.");
            }


Try to add [AllowAnonymous] attribute in EbayCallback method, and check if it works.

@JasonPan I was able to solve this. Issue here was the fact I was debugging application locally localhost:5000 and the redirect URL was set to mysite.com/auth.
So basically it was redirecting through different sites
